# Python Formatting With Math In Print()

Tags: python

To print strings with math addition numbers in Python, what is the correct way doing something like:

```
# Read two inputs from users
a = input("Enter your First Number")
b = input("Enter your Second Number")

# perform type conversion
a = int(a)
b = int(b)

print (f"Result: {a}+{b}")
```

Output:

```
Enter your First Number10
Enter your Second Number10
Result: 10+10
```

Desired output: `Result: 20`

Comment: `print(f"Result: {a+b}")`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current format string `Result: {a}+{b}` prints out `a` and `b` individually as `Result: 10+10` and doesn't perform the addition.

To achieve that, you need to change the [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to `f"Result: {a+b}"` so that the addition happens within the formatting curly braces and the result gets printed

```
print (f"Result: {a+b}")
```

The output will be

```
Result: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = input("Enter your First Number")
b = input("Enter your Second Number")

# perform type conversion
a = int(a)
b = int(b)

print (f"Result: {a + b}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
print (f"Result: {a} + {b}")
```

to

```
print (f"Result: {a + b}")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# Read two inputs from users
a = int(input("Enter your First Number"))
b = int(input("Enter your Second Number"))

print ("Result: {}".format(a+b))
```

Comment: Didn't you mean: `print ("Result: {}".format(a+b))`?

Comment: `f`- strings are a recent addition to the language and are there to make it easy to write complex log messages without making mistakes. Stop using then until you have a better grasp of the `format` string method.